# How to return HttpStatusCode 404 for incorrect url with FallbackPolicy set in AuthorizationOptions?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization

In the web application I'm currently working on there is a requirement for all users to be authenticated. This is currently handled by using an `AuthorizeFilter`.

I now need to be able to apply different authorization policies to different parts of the application, and therefore I wanted to switch from using a global authorization filter to setting the fallback policy (as described in, and recommended by, the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1#require-authenticated-users-1)).

This works as intended, with the exception that requests for resources which don't exist now returns `HttpStatusCode 401` if not authenticated, or `403` if authenticated but some other requirement is not fulfilled (and we have a few in the default/fallback policy). Previously, with the authorization filter solution, a `404` would be returned. I would guess the reason is that the fallback policy is evaluated earlier in the pipeline, than the authorization filter is, but it is still a side-effect I would like to avoid.

(How) Can I get the application to return `404`s like before while utilizing the `FallbackPolicy`? I guess I could use a custom [`IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-5.0) if the application was using `net5.0` (or later), but an upgrade isn't in the short term plan which means the solution must work for `netcoreapp3.1`.

Comment: See the Roles Blob at MSDN : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng I don't see how that is relevant? The problem is not related to using role-based authorization. In fact roles aren't used in the application.

Comment: Maybe this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: You are using OAUTH with a controller and need to capture the exception when authorization fails.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-apibehavioroptionsclienterrormapping

Comment: There is DefaultPolicy apart from FallBackPloicy and it  always require authenticated user(by default).  You can add endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization(); in the 
UseEndpoints builder delegate and will force AuthorizeFilter on all the end points and then you can add your own ploicy on top of it. To keep using FallBackPolicy and return 404 i have suggested an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get the result I was after while utilizing `netcoreapp3.1` by adding a custom authorization handler which extends `DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement`:

```
public class CustomDenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement : DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Resource != null)
        {
            return base.HandleRequirementAsync(context, requirement);
        }
        
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This code just marks the requirement as fulfilled if there is no resource.

Add it the service collection like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomDenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement>();
}
```

---

If using `net5.0+` a custom `IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler` can be used to accomplish the same:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler _defaultHandler = new();

    public async Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
        if ((authorizeResult.Challenged || authorizeResult.Forbidden) && context.GetEndpoint() == null)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            return;
        }

        await _defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
    }
}
```

And added to the service collection:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, CustomAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();
}
```

Comment: @jeancallisti: I can return `Task.CompledtedTask` in my override of `HandelRequirementAsync` because I'm not awaiting any operations myself, and thus have not marked it as [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async). I either return the task from the base method or a complete task which can be awaited by the caller into my method override.

Comment: this is an updated version of my comment, to take in account your clarifications : to anyone who needs to use `await` inside their `HandleRequirementAsync` , simply add the `async` keyword and then simply do `return;` instead of `return Task.CompletedTask;`

Answer (score 1):

To returns 404 with fallback policy:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapControllers();
   endpoints.MapRazorPages();
   endpoints.MapFallbackToController("api/{**slug}", nameof(ErrorController.Error404), "Error");
   endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("{**slug}", "/Public/Errors/404");
});
```

And obviously the action decorated with AllowAnonymous

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Error404()
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

For razor pages:

```
builder.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
  options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Public");
```

Policies

```
options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .RequireRole(LoginEntities.Sede.ToString())
                    .Build();

options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I'm not trying to have 404 errors fallback to another page. I'm trying to have requests to non-existing resources return 404 status code, instead of 401, when using authorization fallback policy (instead of a global authorization policy which specifies that all users must be authenticated).

Comment: ¿Have you tested my answer BEFORE write your comment? I've updated with an evidence ;-)

Comment: Yes, your suggestion does indeed solve my main problem with getting 401 status code, rather than 404 status code. In addition I wanted it to just work like before with returning just the error code, no body, etc. (which I didn't clearly state in my question). I could do this with a custom response in the error controller in your suggestion, but I prefer not having to create the extra controller if I can avoid it. Anyhow, the comment above was poorly worded, which is my bad.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem where by applying FallBackPolicy we are no longer receiving 404,, we can make use of Middlewares.

```
 public class TestMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;

        public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDelegate)
        {
            next = requestDelegate;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            await next(httpContext);
            var ep = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
            if(ep == null)
            {
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Not Found!!!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Above is just a sample implementation of such middleware. We can add this middleware after  UseEndpoints middleware in the pipeline.

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                 endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
app.UseMiddleware<TestMiddleware>();
```

In the middleware code we are using GetEndPoints method on HttContext to understand whether the call actually mapped to any ActionMethod if not we can return 404. So we can have fallback policy and yet we can return 404 for Not found resources